# Проблема java.io.FileNotFoundException: given file does not exist: при чтение базы данных библиотекой jackness

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

При чти чтение базы даных MS Access получаю ошибку

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: given file does not exist: ‪J:\out.accdb
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.open(DatabaseImpl.java:372)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder.open(DatabaseBuilder.java:252)
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder.open(DatabaseBuilder.java:291)
    at File.main(File.java:17)
```

Код

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Database;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Table;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
/**
 *
 * @author AngruAdminAlex
 */
public class File {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException {
 Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new java.io.File("‪J://out.accdb"));




    }
}
```

Указание полного пути не помогает !!
Скидование в корень проекта не помогает !!

```
  java.io.File fx = new java.io.File("‪‪out.accdb");
 boolean xy=fx.canWrite();
 boolean zy = fx.exists();
 if(zy && xy==true)
 { System.out.println("Status"+xy+"   "+zy);

 }
 else {
     System.out.println(fx.getAbsolutePath()+" \n"  +" \n"+xy+" \n" +zy);
  fx.setReadable(true, true);
      fx.setWritable(true, true);
 }
```

Всё время выдает false.Всем пользователям разрешил полный доступ к файлу не помогает !! 
OS =Windows 10 x64bit +JRE181+Netbeans 8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из кода библиотеки:

```
if(!mdbFile.exists() || !mdbFile.canRead()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("given file does not exist: " +
                                        mdbFile);
}
```

Возможно ваш файл не может быть прочитан java, проверьте атрибуты на чтения/запись файла и для каких пользователей они установлены.